# Macro to check for blank cells and highlight them

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro in Excel which could check if cell contents are not blank then I needed a border.

I have tried this macro:

```
Sub testborder()

    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B2:D5")

    'Clear existing
    rRng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

    'Apply new borders
    rRng.BorderAround xlContinuous
    rRng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    rRng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Sub testborder()

    Dim rRng As Range, row As Range, c As Range
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B2:D5")
    'Clear existing
    rRng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

    For Each row In rRng.Rows
      For Each c In row.Columns
        'Apply new borders
        If (c.Value > "") Then c.BorderAround xlContinuous
      Next c
    Next row

End Sub
```

Or, with an even simpler loop:

```
    For Each c In rRng.Cells
      'Apply new borders
      If (c.Value > "") Then c.BorderAround xlContinuous
    Next c
```

Comment: xlNone enumeration happens to work, but is the wrong enumeration. It should be xlLineStyleNone, as referenced here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821622.aspx

Comment: also, why would you loop through the rows?  That is less efficient. Ah, I see your edit -- perhaps borrowed from my answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever test you want. In this example, it checks to see if there is any text in each cell, if so it puts a border around it.

```
Sub BorderForNonEmpty()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("B2:D5")

    ' Clear existing borders
    myRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone


    ' Test each cell and put a border around it if it has content
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If myCell.Text <> "" Then
            myCell.BorderAround (xlContinuous)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```